# How to POST a input string value using thyemeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

> My project based on spring boot,Thymeleaf,mysql,html and Jquery.

i tried to post the input String data to @RestController page,but it received as EMPTY which means null.
Here is my Code Details

**HTML**

```
<form id="addchargesformid" method="post" th:action="@{/addcharge}">  
 <!-- input box add -->
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="chargeName">Add New Charge*</label> 
    <input th:id="chargeName" th:name="chargeName" th:value="${chargeName}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : Maintanence charge">
</div>
<br/>
<button th:type="submit" id="addchargebtnid" class="btn btn-info">Add New Charge</button>
</form>
```

**@RestController**

```
/*To Add Individual charges into list*/
@PostMapping(value="/addcharge")
public ModelAndView doAddCharge(@ModelAttribute String chargeName)
{
    ModelAndView respondResult = new ModelAndView();
    try {
        String result  = serAssignCharges.doAddCharges(chargeName);
        if(result.equals("success"))
        {
            doGetChargesList();
        }
        else {
            respondResult.addObject("warning","sorry! failed to add");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return respondResult;
}
```

Please help me to resolve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't do any binding activities from that form to a model class, and you just want to pass the string, try using @RequestParam instead of @ModelAttribute:

```
public ModelAndView doAddCharge(@RequestParam("chargeName") String chargeName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a code changes....In HTML adding

> th:object="${chargeName}"

in form,adding in input tag

> name="chargeName"

**Full Code Here**

```
 <form id="addchargesformid" method="post" th:action="@{/addcharge}" th:object="${chargeName}">  
     <!-- input box add -->
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="chargeNameid">Add New Charge</label> 
        <input id="chargeNameid" name="chargeName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : Maintanence charge">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button th:type="submit" id="addchargebtnid" class="btn btn-info">Add New Charge</button>
    </form>
```

**@RestController**

> changed @ModelAttribute to @RequestParam

```
/*To Add Individual charges into list*/
    @PostMapping(value="/addcharge")
    public ModelAndView doAddCharge(@RequestParam String chargeName)
    {
        ModelAndView respondResult = new ModelAndView();
        try {
            String result  = serAssignCharges.doAddCharges(chargeName);
            if(result.equals("success"))
            {
                respondResult = new ModelAndView("redirect:" + "/getchargeslist"); /*it is redirecting from
                                                                                        "/addcharge" to "/getchargeslist" */ 
            }
            else {
                respondResult.addObject("warning","sorry! failed to add");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return respondResult;
    }
```